# Can't compile CRC library in rust include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/crc16_constants.rs"));

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, crc

I recently found a very interesting library called `Exonum` and this library is using the [CRC library](https://github.com/mrhooray/crc-rs).

Every time I try to compile the simple test project in Windows 10 I am greeted with:

```
error: couldn't read "C:\\Users\\XXXXXX\\OUTDIR/crc16_constants.rs": The 
system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)
 --> src\crc16.rs:8:1
  |
8 | include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/crc16_constants.rs"));
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: Could not compile `crc`.
```

I have tried setting the `out_dir` however it didn't help. There seems to be `build.rs` file in that library which should export this file, but it does not do it before the build.
Anyone have the same issue?

#### EDIT1:

After point in comments I removed the `OUT_DIR` environment variable and changed the string in the source there still seems to be a problem. The output from compilation is as follows:

```
error: environment variable `OUT_DIR` not defined
 --> crc16.rs:8:18
  |
8 | include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "\\crc16_constants.rs"));
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: couldn't read "0\\crc16_constants.rs": The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)
 --> crc16.rs:8:1
  |
8 | include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "\\crc16_constants.rs"));
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: Could not compile `crc`.
```

Comment: `C:\\Users\\XXXXXX\\OUTDIR/crc16_constants.rs` - this path looks weird, no? Have you tried substituting `/` with a `\ ` in `"/crc16_constants.rs"`?

Comment: Can you add some more details? What did you call for compiling your program? Do you use Cargo?

Comment: That zero in the path is probably a problem, maybe i have to set beforehand the OUT_DIR to source folder of the library?

Comment: You definitely want to set that variable if you want to use it.

Comment: Just did it again, and it does not work, the file is not generated, i can see the code in build.rs its there, but it won't be executed somehow.

Comment: It's hard to answer the question if you don't tell us how do you compile the project. What are your exact steps?

Comment: Okay I just enter the place where Cargo.toml is and I execute     cargo build.

Comment: Looking at that project, I don't see the build script listed in the `Cargo.toml`.  So the reason it's not being generated could be because the build script is never run.  This would be the case if you're using a sufficiently old version of Cargo, though I don't know in which version the behaviour changed.  What versions of rustc & cargo are you using?

Comment: Um there is cargo.toml inside examples of the platform \exonum\examples\timestamping\backend. This is the one I am using, the rustc & cargo versions are rustc 1.25.0 (84203cac6 2018-03-25) and  cargo 0.16.0-nightly (3568be9 2016-11-26). I just installed them from the official site.

Comment: *cargo 0.16.0-nightly (3568be9 2016-11-26)* - this is pretty old.

Comment: You may try [rustup](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs#installation) and check, if it's working.

Comment: Yeah; the cargo that shipped with Rust 1.25.0 should be cargo 0.26.0.  You've somehow ended up with a seriously weird configuration.

Comment: I can confirm that with a fresh, rustup-installed 1.25.0 on Windows 7, the `timestamping\backend` example compiles just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the comments, the solution was to simply update Rust and check `PATH` for older `cargo.exe`.